# Do Russian oil investments abroad fall into the scope of the sanctions?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, sanctions, foreign-direct-investment

In response to the [Ukrainian war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine) Europe, the US and few more countries have set up some sanctions against Russian interests, including Russian oil production. However Russian oil and gas companies have a lot of investments outside the Russian Federations and I would like to know whether those interests have been targeted by the sanctions.

For example Lukoil have petrol stations in [18 countries](https://lukoil.com/Business/Downstream/PetroleumProductSales/PetroleumProductRetail) including at least 6 EU countries, but they seem to be working normally:

https://lukoil.be/fr/index.cfm

https://lukoil.bg/en/ForMotorists/PetrolStations

https://lukoil.it/en/ProductsAndServices/Petrolstations

Moreover. Lukoil is developing many oil and gas fields [abroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lukoil#Foreign_projects). Rosneft controls the [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkuk%E2%80%93Ceyhan_Oil_Pipeline) that transports most of the oil produced in the Kirkuk region, that is a big share of Iraqi oil.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, Gazprom tried to divest itself of Gazprom Germania. As Germany interprets German law, this sale would have required the prior permission of regulatory bodies, exactly **because** Gazprom Germania was running gas stations and pipelines. Since there was no such permission, the Bundesnetzagentur has [taken over administration](https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Fachthemen/ElektrizitaetundGas/Versorgungssicherheit/aktuelle_gasversorgung/Treuhand/LetterOfComfort.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1) of Gazprom Germania.
Russia has complained about this "seizure" while Germany insists that it is only temporary, with an end date set for September 22th.

Comment: I think some version of this is typical for these Russian foreign investments. The local companies can still operate on their own but if they want to transfer money or goods to or from their Russian home company they are bound by the same sanctions as everyone else.

Comment: This is an isolated event, it does not define a legal scope.